# Find all $2\times2$ matrices that have pure imaginary eigenvalues.

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Find all $2 \times 2$ matrices that have pure imaginary eigenvalues. That is, determine conditions on the entries of a matrix that guarantee the matrix has pure imaginary eigenvalues.
>   \begin{bmatrix}a & b\\
> c & d \\
> \end{bmatrix}

$$(a - \lambda)(d-\lambda)-bc = 0  $$

$$\lambda = \frac{a+d \pm\sqrt{(a+d)^2-4(ad-bc)}}{2}$$

Focusing on the things inside the square root:

$$(a-d)^2 \lt - 4bc $$

One case is when $a=d$, $b\gt0$ and $c\lt0$ or $b\lt0$ and $c\gt0$. I am wondering what other cases lie in there?

Comment: Note: Pure imaginary means the real part is zero.

Comment: Are $a,b,c,d$ real numbers? Note also that the real part of $\lambda$ has to be $0$.

Comment: could you give an example to show your meaning?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm going to address this for *real* matrices; our OP afsdf dfsaf's use of "$>$" and "$<$" in his question suggests, or even tacitly implies, that this is the case of primary interest.

For any $2 \times 2$ real matrix

$A = \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix}, \tag{1}$

it is well-known, and easy to see, that the characteristic pilynomial $p_A(x)$ is

$p_A(x) = x^2 - \text{Tr}(A) x + \det(A), \tag{2}$

where $\text{Tr}(A)$ and $ \det(A)$ are the trace and determinant of $A$, respectively.  Applying the quadratic formula to

$p_A(x) = x^2 - \text{Tr}(A) x + \det(A) = 0, \tag{3}$

we obtain

$\lambda_\pm = -\dfrac{1}{2}(-\text{Tr}(A) \pm \sqrt{(\text{Tr}(A))^2 - 4\det(A)}(, \tag{4}$

so in order that the $\lambda_\pm$ be purely imaginary we must have $\text{Tr}(A) = 0$ and from this $\det(A) > 0$.  $\text{Tr}(A) = 0$ implies $d = -a$, whence

$A = \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & -a \end{bmatrix}, \tag{5}$

with

$\det(A) = -a^2 -bc > 0, \tag{6}$

or

$a^2 + bc < 0. \tag{7}$

Hope this helps.  Cheerio,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Comment: Do you mean $\lambda =\frac{1}{2} (Tr(A) \pm \sqrt{(Tr(A))^2-4 det(A)}$? Why do you have $-1/2$ and $-Tr(A)$?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for real $2\times 2$ matrices, (with eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$) then the characteristic polynomial should be of the form $p(\lambda)=\lambda^2+s$, $s\ge 0$. Hence, if
$$
A=\left(\begin{matrix} a&b\\c&d\end{matrix}\right),
$$
then $\lambda_1+\lambda_2=a+d=0$, (i.e. $d=-a$) and $\lambda_1\lambda_2=ad-bc\ge 0$ or
$-bc\ge a^2$.

Comment: Strictly greater, $ad-bc>0$. Need a positive determinant with the zero trace.

Comment: does a and d must be the opposite sign?

Comment: @afsdf dfsaf Yes. They are additive inverses of each other as said in this answer. $d=-a$, or the matrix trace equals zero.

Answer (score 0):

A sufficient and concise condition is:
$$A^{*}=-A$$
That is: for all $a,b \in \mathbb{R}, z \in \mathbb{C}$:
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}ia & z \\ -\overline{z} &ib \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: what is $A^{\dagger}?$

Comment: [Conjugate transpose](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_transpose)

Comment: I don't really think this helps @afsdfdfsaf follow how this was reached or why it works, perhaps some explanation?

Comment: @unwitting I (really) have to leave my PC for a while.. Not avoiding or anything :). I will add all the details when I'll be back. BTW, trying to derive the wanted properties from the above is a really fun exercise!

Comment: The condition $A^\dagger =  -A$ is sufficient but not necessary!